# How can you alter the Volterra-Lotka system to obtain a model of cooperative species?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Volterra-Lotka system for two competitive species is:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dt} = x(-Ax-By+C) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = y(-DX-Ey+F)
\end{equation*}

where $x,y\geq 0 $ and $ A,B,C,D,E,F$ all positive.

The Model system for cooperative species is:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dt} = x(-Ax+By+C) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = y(DX-Ey+F)
\end{equation*}

but I dont know who to explaining  using words.

what happens when $x$ decreases or when $y$ decrease. And if $x$ increases then $y$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a **balanced system** and then consider what happens in the case of sudden jumps.

Look at the fist equation. When **x or y** increases, x' will become negative (-A and -B) and will try to balance the system back. Since all members of x and y compete.
Same goes for the second equation. When **x or y** increases, y' will become negative (-D and -E) to balance it out, since everyone competes.
Same goes for a decrease in x or y.

Now look at the second set. Just as before, when x increases, x' will become negative (-A) to balance the effects. However, when y increases, x will become positive (+B) because x and y cooperate and an increase in y means they can cooperate more so it is possible for x to increase to match y.
Same goes for y, and a decrease in x or y.